# what is the best way to make css animation working with scrolling (on react)

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to remake this website as a training : https://www.agap2.fr/

I started with the "zoom" animation on screen 4. I succeeded to do it but I would like to know the best way to do it.

For the moment, here what I did :

```
useEffect(() => {
    function watchScroll() {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", logit);
    }
    watchScroll();
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", logit);
    };
  });
```

Inside the logit function, I check the size, width or radius to change according to window.pageYOffset.

Here's the div for a circle :

```
<div
          style={{
            position:"fixed",
            display:visibility,
            height: diameter + "px",
            width: diameter + "px",
            top: posCercle[1] + "px",
            left: posCercle[0] + "px",
            backgroundColor: "#ff0",
            borderRadius: "999px",
            boxSizing: "border-box"
          }}
        />
```

Is there simplest way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [react-animation-on-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animation-on-scroll?activeTab=readme)

```
npm install react-animation-on-scroll --save
```

###### Include animate.css in your project:

HTML:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
</head>
```

*Or:*

```
npm install --save animate.css
```

```js
import "animate.css/animate.min.css";
```

```js
import { AnimationOnScroll } from 'react-animation-on-scroll';

<AnimationOnScroll animateIn="animate__bounceIn">
  <h2>Some Text</h2>
</AnimationOnScroll>
```

---

#### [react-reveal](https://www.react-reveal.com/docs/)

```
npm install react-reveal --save
```

React reveal has multiple different effects (like [fade](https://www.react-reveal.com/examples/common/fade/), [flip](https://www.react-reveal.com/examples/common/flip/), [rotate](https://www.react-reveal.com/examples/common/rotate/), [bounce](https://www.react-reveal.com/examples/common/bounce/), etc.).
They're all very easy to use:

```js
import Zoom from 'react-reveal/Zoom';
```

```js
<Zoom>
  <p>Markup that will be revealed on scroll</p>
</Zoom>
```

```js
<Zoom>  
  <CustomComponent />
</Zoom>
```

---

#### Without an external library

- Keep track of the element with a ref

```js
const refRef = useRef(null)

return <div ref={refRef} />
```

- Scroll event listener with *useLayoutEffect*

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {

  window.addEventListener(‘scroll’, onScroll)

  return () => window.removeEventListener(‘scroll’, onScroll)

}, [])
```

- Check the user's scroll position

> Grab the “ref” of the animated element and check the Y coordinate of its top using *getBoundingClientRect()* API. Check a user’s scroll action by knowing if the scroll position is greater than the top of the element.

```js
const topPos = refRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top

const onScroll = () => {

  const scrollPos = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight

  if (topPos < scrollPos) {

    // enter animation code here

  }

}
```

- Use React’s inline styles or Styled Components to create simple animations

> Example of a *fade in* animation

```js
const [show, doShow] = useState({

  itOne: false,

  itTwo: false,

  itThree: false,

})

const refRef = useRef(null)

return (

  <>

    <Div animate={show.itOne} ref={refRef} />

  </>

)

// component we are animating

const Div = styled.div`

  transform: translateX(${({ animate }) => (animate ? ‘0’ : ‘-50vw’)});

  transition: transform 1s;

  height: 650px;

  width: 250px;

  background-color: green;
```